# How can we filter datatable in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, datatable

I have specific requirement with datatable which i am not able to get. Please help me to solve my problem. My query is as below

1. The datatable i have with data is

> ```
>        C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
> R1    1   2   3   4   25
> R2    6   7   8   24  10
> R3    11  22  13  14  15
> R4    16  17  23  19  20
> R5    21  7   18  9   5
> ```

2. In output i would like to have max value from each colum with position (index) of row and colum as following

> ```
> Value  Row Column
> 21    R5  C1
> 22    R3  C2
> 23    R4  C3
> 24    R2  C4
> 25    R1  C5
> ```

Can anyone please help me, how should i achieve result?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming column names are C1, C2, C3, C4, C5.

Pseudo code/Algorithm.

```
int C1_MaxValue, C2_MaxValue, C3_MaxValue, C4_MaxValue, C5_MaxValue;
string C1_Row, C2_Row, C3_Row, C4_Row, C5_Row;

//Initialize row1 values as max values.
C1_MaxValue = DataTable.Rows[1]["C1"];
C2_MaxValue = DataTable.Rows[1]["C2"];
C3_MaxValue = DataTable.Rows[1]["C3"];
C4_MaxValue = DataTable.Rows[1]["C4"];
C5_MaxValue = DataTable.Rows[1]["C5"];

//Set R1 as row for max values.
C1_Row = C2_Row = C3_Row = C4_Row = C5_Row = DataTable.Rows[1][Row1];

For (i=2 to RowCount -1)

 if(Datatable.Rows[i]["C1"] > C1_MaxValue) 
 {       
      C1_MaxValue = Datatable.Rows[i][C1]; 
      C1_Row = Datatable.Rows[i][0];
 }
 //Do the above for all other columns.
End For
```

At the end of this for the above variables should contain the max values and corresponding max rows.